# how to retrieve app info from windows phone Apps+Games store

Tags: android, ios, json, windows-phone, app-id

Is there anybody know how to retrieve app info from windows phone App+Games store?

For example, I can obtain an iOS app details in the form of JSON like this using iTunes search api:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=454638411

And I can obtain an Android app details in the form of JSON like this using Android Query service:

https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=com.mobage.ww.a1912.Godus_Android

But I haven't found any solution to retrieve windows phone app details by app id. Any idea?